# C# formatting json array

Tags: c#, json

Hi I need to make an json array look like:

```
"list_id": { "32323":"subscribed"}
```

Current Code :

```
public static class createContact
 {
 [FunctionName("createContact")]
  public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
      {
       log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
                  
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                   
       #region DeserializeObjects
        
   PayloadReceived deserializePayloadReceived=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayloadReceived(requestBody);
    
    FinalPayload finalPayload = new FinalPayload 
    {
       list_id = deserializePayloadReceived.listId,
    };
    
     var serializefinalPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalPayload );
    
     return new OkObjectResult(serializefinalPayload);
```

classes

```
 public class PayloadReceived
  {
    public List<list_id> listId { get; set; }
  }
  public class list_id
  {
     public string Listid { get; set; }
     public string subscribbed { get; set; }
   }
   public class FinalPayload
   {
     public List<list_id> list_id { get; set; }
   }
```

Current code makes an array object :

```
{
    "list_id": [
        {
            "Listid": "32100",
            "subscribed": "subscribed"
        }
    ],
```

What do I need to do. To make the array look like:

```
"list_id": { "32323":"subscribed"}
```

Comment: That's just part of a JSON object, not a JSON array. This isn't even valid JSON. A valid JSON object would be `{"list_id": { "32323":"subscribed"}}`

Comment: To produce the key/value pairs you'd have to create a Dicttionary of the key/value pairs and serialize that instead of the original object, eg `var dict=payload.list_id.ToDictionary(l=>l.ListId,l=>l.subscribed)`. To create a valid JSON object from this, you could create an anonymous type, eg `var it=new {list_id=dict};`